# Is the zero set of a differential Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove the following theorem.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and define
> $$\mathcal A:=\{a\in\mathbb{R}: f\text{ is differentiable in } a \text{ and } f'(a)=0\},$$ then $\mathcal A$ is a Borel set and $f(\mathcal A)$ has measure $0$.

I managed to prove that $\mathcal A$ is a Borel set but I'm struggling to prove that $f(\mathcal A)$ has measure zero. To do so I can use the following theorem:

Let $\epsilon>0$, $\mathcal Y$ be a Lebesgue-integrable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function s.t. $\forall\,y\in\mathcal Y$, $f$ is differentiable in $y$ and $|f'(y)| < \epsilon$, then $\exists\,\mathcal B\subset\mathbb{R}$ Borel s.t. $f(\mathcal Y)\subset\mathcal B$ and $\lambda(\mathcal B)\leq \epsilon \lambda(\mathcal Y)$.

Now I assume I have to use this theorem for $\mathcal Y=\mathcal A$, so that $\exists\mathcal B\subset\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(\mathcal A)\subset\mathcal B \text{ and } \lambda(\mathcal B) \leq \lambda(\mathcal A)$, and thus $\lambda(f(\mathcal A)) \leq \lambda(\mathcal B) \leq \epsilon \lambda(\mathcal A) \ \ \forall \epsilon>0$ so that $f(\mathcal A)$ has measure $0$ if $\lambda(\mathcal A)<\infty$.

However to use the theorem mentioned above I need $\mathcal A$ to be Lebesgue-measurable, yet I don't know how to prove this. Also, I assume if $\mathcal A$ is Lebesgue-measurable $\lambda(A)<\infty$ so that my proof is correct; but even if $\mathcal A$ is Lebesgue-measurable; is that true?

Comment: Boreal measurable sets are always Lebesgue measurable. To get $\lambda(A)<\infty$, look at $A \cap [-n,n]$ instead.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean $\lambda(A\cap[-n,n])=0 \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A\cap[-n,n]$ s.t. $\lambda(A)=\lambda(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(A\cap[-n,n])\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \lambda(A\cap[-n,n])=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ $0 = 0$?

Comment: More or less. In the end, you do not want to show that $A$ has measure zero, but that $f(A)$ has measure zero, so you will use that $f(A) = \bigcup_n f(A \cap [-n,n])$ is a null-set as a countable union of null-sets.

Comment: Well, by the theorem I mentioned in the original post (which I'm supposed to use, according to this exercise) it is enough to show $\lambda(A)$ to be finite, so that $\lambda(f(A))$ is zero, as $\lambda(A)\leq\epsilon\lambda(f(A))$ holds $\forall \epsilon>0$. I think I just correctly proved $\lambda(A)$ to be finite (zero, in fact), but I must admit I do not directly see a way to prove $\lambda(A\cap[-n,n]) = 0$, which I used to do so.

Comment: My idea was to apply the theorem to $A \cap [-n,n]$ instead of $A$. You then just have to show $\lambda(A \cap [-n,n]) < \infty$, which is trivial. In the end, you can use my union argument from the previous comment to conclude that $f(A)$ is a null-set, because $f(A \cap[-n,n])$ is, for each $n$.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, thank you. Forget the question I just posted in this comment haha, I figured it out already so I'm editing this. Thank you!

Comment: Is this not just Sard's Theorem?

Comment: @PeteCaradonna : Here, Sard's theorem requires that $f$ is once continuously differentiable.  We only have that $f$ is differentiable at various points, but we have no promise that this derivative is continuous.  In fact, differentiable but not continuously differentiable is the case for "most" functions, but not the functions we usually write down.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3338788/123905 for an example.