# The continuous function that is differentiable on the interior of the rectangular is differentiable even on its boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $I:=[0,1]$:be an interval, 
$\varphi:{I}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ : **continious on ${I^2}$ and differntiable on $Int({I}^{2})$** ,
 
$\delta_{(1,c)}:Int(I)\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be defined by $t\in Int(I)\mapsto(t,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$

> **My Question**
>
>   For above-mentioned $\varphi$ and $\delta_{(1,c)}$, Is the  $\varphi\circ\delta_{(1,0)}(t) = \varphi(t,0)$ a differntiable on $Int(I)$?

If the $\varphi\circ\delta_{(1,0)}$ is differntiable on $Int(I)$, please give me proof or tell me the literature that has description of proof. If not, please give me a counterexample.

Here, $Int({I}^{2})$ is the interior of ${I}^2$ and $Int(I)$ is the interior of ${I}$: these are largest open subset of  ${I}^{2}$ and $I$ respectively. 
For example, $Int(I)=(0,1)=\{t\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ 0<t<1 \}$. 
Note that the $(0,1)$ of the previous sentence is an open interval, not a vector.
The definition of differentiable is as described in following page:
[Are there any functions that are differentiable but not continuously-differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338751/)

**P.S.**
I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions.

Comment: What about $\varphi(x,y) = x^{1/2}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thank you for your comment. I think your $\varphi$ seems not to be a counterexample. Because,
 $\varphi\circ\delta_{(1,0)}(t) = \varphi(t,0)=\sqrt{t}$ seems differentiable on $(0,1)$ . Even though we change x and y, it seems not to be counterexample.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Perhaps you seem to mention the differentiability at the vector $(0,1)$.
However, my question is "About differentiability in the interval (0,1)=Int(I)".

Comment: @Sangchul  :Thank you for your comment. Your $varphi$ certainly be a counterexample. (It is not differentiable at $t=1/2$.)
Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Glad it helped, I migrated my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Migrated from comment)* Consider the function

$$ \varphi(x, y) = \left( (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 \right)^{1/2}. $$

Then $\varphi$ is continuous on $I^2$ and differentiable on $\operatorname{Int}(I^2)$, but the map

$$ \varphi \circ \delta_{(1,0)} \quad : \quad t \mapsto \varphi(t, 0) = \left| t - \tfrac{1}{2} \right| $$

is not differentiable on all of $\operatorname{Int}(I)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.